# Como salvar e ler uma matriz salva do diretório no Scilab?

Tags: scilab

Estou tento dificuldades para salvar uma matriz de dados no Scilab, eu uso o comando save('diretótio\nome','matriz'), mas na hora de usar o LOAD para reutilizar a matriz sempre o que carrega é uma variavel Booleana, alguém sabe onde estou errado ao usar o save?

Comment: Acho que você precisará dar mais informações sobre o seu código para que alguém tenha como responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: Coloque seu código e melhore sua pergunta para eu poder ajuda-lo melhor. Tentei por o básico na resposta mas não sei se consegui atingir o objetivo em lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de como fazer funcionar a função load é assim:

```
a=eye(2,2);
b=ones(a);
save('vals.dat',a,b);
clear a
clear b
load('vals.dat','a','b');
disp(a);
disp(b);
```

//para ler a matriz

```
    [x]=read(file-desc,m,n,[format])
[x]=read(file-desc,m,n,k,format)
```

Para escrever uma matriz pode usar  algo do tipo:

```
    write(file-desc,a,[format])
write(file-desc,a,k,format)
//para colocar a matriz no arquivo
// e depois pode continuar com os procedimentos padrão como load...
```